# Open new window out of iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I currently have a page that contains an iframe. That iframe is opening a page from a 3rd party site that contains a form.

The page that I show in the iframe is:

http://local.amazon.com/subscribe

I do not have control of the page that appears in the iframe since it is from a 3rd party.

What I want to happen is after the user clicks on Continue and then clicks on Subscribe, the next page needs to break out of my iframe and open full-window.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot detect clicks that happen on pages that are not under your control (same origin policy).

Answer (score 0):

Try `target="_blank"` within an iframe and `top.location = self.location.href`.

Comment: hmmn...not really what I am looking for :)

Comment: you can inject some code to your iframe, and do the stuff you need. $('#myiframe').contents().find('sometagid').click( function(){ alert(0) } );